# Form redirect with query vars to page

Tags: query

EDIT: SOLVED query var and custom post type had the same name `story`

This has been bugging me for few hours so any help is appreciated.

I am building a theme, and I have a page named edit-story `localhost/wp3/edit-story/` , which uses a template `page_edit-story.php` . This page has a form that calls admin-post.php, and I have a function in my `functions.php` that's processing `POST` information and is redirecting back to `localhost/wp3/edit-story/`. This part works fine. Now when I add `add_query_arg` to pass back some information.

```
$redirect = get_site_url() . '/edit-story/';
$redirect_query = add_query_arg( array('story' => 'updated', 'sid' => $story_id ), $redirect );
wp_redirect( $redirect_query );
exit;
```

I get sent to `localhost/wp3/edit-story/?story=value$sid=value` which displays `archive.php` (or something similar). I want to go back to `localhost/wp3/edit-story/` where I will be able to access `story` and `sid` via get_query_var(  ).

Query vars are filtered.

```
function add_custom_query_vars( $vars ){  
   $vars[] = "story";
   $vars[] = "sid";

   return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_vars' );
```

Comment: Are either `story` and `sid` query vars associated to custom types, meaning do you have a post type or taxonomy registered that are also using one of these query vars?

Comment: These are the only two query vars I have so far. I do have a custom post type registered with post type key `story`.

Comment: Edit: You were right I just tried changing query var `story` to `test` and it worked. Thank You